# Discord.py - How to make a Webhook send a message after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a webhook that sends a message ever hour in a channel on discord but cannot find anything online about it and was unable to code it myself. Anyone have any ideas?

I have tried to create something using datetime but couldn't.

Comment: Why do you need to develop a webhook? Can't be a bot?
The [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) module of `discord.py` allows you to easily create a loop that runs every hour.

Comment: Needs to be a webhook as this is an addition to an already made webhook that has been coded already

Comment: So you can simply create a while loop, which will send the message and sleep for 1 hour.